# control xterm using pseudo terminal in C

Tags: c, linux, xterm

I started writing a simple chat application `(Linux)` using sockets. I wanted to launch a separate terminal `(xterm)` for a chat. So I tried to fork and exec an xterm from the chat application. But I am unable to control the new exec'ed xterm window using my chat application. I used `dup2(slave, STDIN_FILENO)`, `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`, but still, the new xterm window is not using the 'slave' terminal for its I/O.

(I tried https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/, https://rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html and code from "Advanced programming in Unix environment)

I have also tried xterm -S option. It is working, but I am not satisfied using it.

Comment: Why would you want to launch xterm? It's outdated and not installed by default everywhere.

Comment: Without some sample program (from OP to illustrate the problem), or from commenters to point out constructive solutions, there's not much to discuss here.

Comment: ok. In the link http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html, pls refer mypty3.c. It is mentioned that telnet, xterm, rlogin etc can be used. But I am unable to use xterm. And I dont want to specifically launch 'xterm', any terminal emulator will do for my needs. I just want a separate one as a 'chat window'.

Comment: All of the terminal emulators do some special initialization to attach to a *device*; xterm has the special `-S` option to provide a way to bypass (some of) that.  I don't recall other terminal emulators with an equivalent.  For `-S` in use, the [multixterm](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html) tcl script works.

Comment: So is there no other way to launch a separate window/terminal for my requirement mention above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do something similar (in C under Linux):

```
// Open a pseudo-terminal master
int ptmx = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
if (ptmx == -1) {
    printf("Failed to open pseudo-terminal master-slave for use with xterm. Aborting...");
    quit(); // closes any open streams and exits the program
} else if (unlockpt(ptmx) != 0) {
    printf("Failed to unlock pseudo-terminal master-slave for use with xterm (errno. %d). Aborting...", errno);
    close(ptmx);
    quit();
}
else if (grantpt(ptmx) != 0) {
    printf("Failed to grant access rights to pseudo-terminal master-slave for use with xterm (errno. %d). Aborting...", errno);
    close(ptmx);
    quit();
}

// open the corresponding pseudo-terminal slave (that's us)
char *pts_name = ptsname(ptmx);
printf("Slave-master terminal: %s", pts_name);
int pts = open(pts_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

// launch an xterm that uses the pseudo-terminal master we have opened
char *xterm_cmd;
asprintf(&xterm_cmd, "xterm -S%s/%d", pts_name, ptmx);
FILE *xterm_stdout = popen(xterm_cmd, "r");
if (xterm_stdout <= 0) {
    printf("Failed to open xterm process. Aborting...");
    ptmx = 0;
    close(ptmx);
    quit();
}

// Set the stdin / stdout to be the pseudo-terminal slave
dup2(pts, STDIN_FILENO);
dup2(pts, STDOUT_FILENO);

printf("This appears in the terminal window.\n");
```

Now anything getting entered in the terminal is fed to the program's `stdin`, and anything that the program outputs to `stdout` appears in the terminal. You can use the `readline` library, `linenoise`, or even `curses` at will.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a command directly to xterm using `-e` option. You can create the chat itself (read fron stdin and write to stdout etc.) in a separate binary and xterm will only need to execute that binary.